# Adding individual elements in two lists (?)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to do a code where I have to show on which day both teams had the same number of runs in total. In 3 days, the Swifts got 1, 3 and 3 runs and the Semaphores got 2, 2, and 6 runs. They both got a total of 4 runs on day 2. How would I show this? This is what I have so far:

```
numOfDays = int(input("Number of days in the season:"))

swifts = list(input("Number of runs the Swifts made per day:"))

semaphores = list(input("Number of runs the Semaphores made per day:"))
while True:
    if len(semaphores) and len(swifts)!=numOfDays:
        print("Invalid")
        break
```

How would I output on which day they both had the same number of runs in total?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following loop:

```
for idx in range(numOfDays):
    if swifts[idx] == semaphores[idx]:
        print("Both had", swifts[idx] ,"runs on day,"idx)
```

Answer (score 0):

Uhm, it´s pseudo code so you´ll have to translate it to python:

```
numOfDays = input("num of days")
swifts = input("Runs swifts")
semaphores = input("runs semaphores")

if len(semaphores) != numOfDays and len(swifts) != numOfDays:
    print("day count mismatch")
    return

swiftsTotal = 0
semaphoresTotal = 0

for i in range(0, numOfDays):
    swiftsTotal += swifts[i]
    semaphoresTotal += semaphores[i]
    if swiftsTotal == semaphoresTotal:
        print("Both had " + str(runsSwifts) + " runs on day " + str(i))
        // remove the next line if you want to see all day with same runs
        return
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
# You don't need the number of days 
#numOfDays = int(input("Number of days in the season:"))
swifts = input("Number of runs the Swifts made per day (comma delimited):")
semaphores = input("Number of runs the Semaphores made per day (comma delimited):")

swifts = list(map(int, swifts.split(',')))        # runs as integer lists
semaphores = list(map(int, semaphores.split(',')))

sum_swifts = 0
sum_semaphores = 0
for i in range(min(len(swifts), len(semaphores))): # loop length of shorter list
  sum_swifts += swifts[i]
  sum_semaphores += semaphores[i]
  if sum_swifts == sum_semaphores:
    print(f'It took {i+1} days')
    break
else:
  print('Two teams never had the same number of runs')
```

**Test**

*Test 1*

```
Number of runs the Swifts made per day (comma delimited):1,3,3
Number of runs the Semaphores made per day (comma delimited):2,2,2
It took 2 days
```

*Test 2 (shows works even when number days different for the two teams*

```
Number of runs the Swifts made per day (comma delimited):1,2,3,4,5
Number of runs the Semaphores made per day (comma delimited):2,2,2
It took 3 days
```